# Erase and delete iterator of vector

Tags: c++, iterator, delete-operator, erase

I have a vector of `flowers` which contain each name of the flowers that was inserts by the user, I put the names using `push_back`. In the following function I need to delete the name from the vector, I don't understand what happens on lines (1) and (2).

p.s. what happens when I'm using `erase`. Does the same the iterator was pointed on is not exist any more but the vector is not getting shorter, nor does the vector get shorter so all the cell of the vector "move" left.

```
void FlowersDB::DeleteFlowers(const std::string& FName)
{
    for(FlowersVec_it iter=Flowers.begin(); iter!=Flowers.end(); iter++)
    {
        if((*iter)->GetFlowerName()==rName)
            {
                delete *iter;//(1)
                flowers.erase(iter); //(2)
                return;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could show definition `Flowers`? But it seems like the vector contains  pointers. So you dereference the iterator, to get the pointer, delete the object there, and then remove the entry from vector.

Comment: Why do you think the vector is not getting shorter?

Comment: Is `flowers` supposed to be the same as `Flowers`?  Is `rName` supposed to be the same as `FName`?